# Whenever I use the primary key in a SQL query, I get an SqlException. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: sql, exception, primary-key, visual-c#-express-2010

I am normally too impatient to find solutions to my problems too wait for answers to forum posts; I prefer to find answers posted to similar questions asked by other people. But after THOROUGH googling, I've still not found the answer to this one. So here goes, my first question posted on this fine forum:

I am trying to ask a SQL query to give me the smallest primary key in a set of records. Here is the command text I used:

```
SELECT MIN(LineNo) FROM Code
```

"LineNo", an int, is the primary key in my table "Code"

I then get the error message:

> "SqlException was unhandled Incorrect syntax near the keyword
>   'LineNo'."

I then played around with some other queries, and found anything works as long as I don't use the primary key in the query. If I try to select it, it fails. If I try to select something else, where the primary key is a certain value, it fails.

I am using Visual C# 2010 Express. As for the data base, all i know it's what's called a "Service-based Database" in Visual C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LineNo` is a reserved word. Use Identifiers to get around this:

```
SELECT MIN([LineNo]) FROM Code
```

Comment: Thanks GarethD! That was a super-fast answer! And yep, it was that simple to fix....

Answer (score 0):

LineNo appears to be a keyword. Try wrapping it in square brackets

```
SELECT MIN([LineNo]) FROM table
```

Comment: I tried... But I'm not allowed to until I have 15 reputation lol!